# select text between two line breaks in sublime text

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext3

I was wondering if there is any shortcut key for sublime text(3) or plugin for selecting all the text between two line breaks. 
For example:

```
    $search_box = Input::get('search_box');
    $city_code  = Input::get('city_code');
    $check_in   = Input::get('check_in');
    $check_out  = Input::get('check_out');

    $noofrooms  = Input::get('noofrooms');
    $adultguest = Input::get('adultguest');
    $childguest = Input::get('childguest');
    $childage   = Input::get('childage');

    Session::put('adultguest', $adultguest);
    Session::put('childguest', $childguest);
    Session::put('childage', $childage);
```

In above code, I want to select all the text from`$noofrooms  = Input::get('noofrooms');` to `Input::get('childage');` with shortcut key at once. Is there any?

Comment: You can get pretty close if you use the find panel with this regex: `\n\n[\s\S]*\n\n`. This searches for any number of whitespace and non-whitespace characters in between two line breaks. This will also select the line breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following line to `Preferences > Key Bindings - User`

```
  { "keys": ["alt+p"], "command": "expand_selection_to_paragraph" }
```

(You can change the `"alt+p"` to whatever key combo you want)